# Getting import error with sub modules of PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-3.6, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to install and use PyQt5 on Ubuntu 14.04. Before this, I had been using Ubuntu 18.04 and I had no problems with the installation and use of PyQt5. Because of some technical needs of a project, I need to use 14.04 instead.

After I first launch Ubuntu this is the order that I install things:

Install Python 3.6:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.6
```

Install QT5

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install qtcreator
sudo apt-get install qt5-default
```

Install PyQt5

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5
sudo apt-get install pyqt5-dev-tools
sudo apt-get install qttools5-dev-tools
```

After this is completed, I run this test code to see if I get an import error:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
```

When I run it, I get this error. It gives an error for any sub module of PyQt5. On Ubuntu 18.04, I followed the same installation steps as above for qt5 and pyqt5 and it worked perfectly. (Did not install python 3.6 because it is already installed with Ubuntu 18).

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/ms/test.py", line 2, in 
> from PyQt5 import QtCore
> ImportError: cannot import name 'QtCore'

I have also tried installing pyqt5 with pip or pip3, but I get an error.

```
pip3 install pyqt5
```

Error:

```
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_ms/pyqt5
Storing debug log for failure in /home/ms/.pip/pip.log
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have been working on trying to fix this for the past couple days with still no idea what the problem could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following steps use to install PyQt5 in a docker with ubuntu: 14.04:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.6
sudo apt-get install curl
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
sudo python3.6 get-pip.py
sudo python3.6 -m pip install --upgrade pip
sudo python3.6 -m pip install pyqt5==5.9.2
sudo apt-get install '^libxcb.*-dev' libx11-xcb-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libxrender-dev libxi-dev libxkbcommon-dev libxkbcommon-x11-dev libfontconfig1
python3.6 -c "from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets"
```

Comment: Why is a docker necessary? I will try this out.

Comment: @RamboPenguin I did not say that docker is necessarily used but that I use it for my ubuntu 14.04 based docker and it will probably work for you.

Comment: I am getting this error now when I try to run an actual GUI script: /home/ms/Documents/GUI/3StepTest.py 
/usr/bin/python3.6: relocation error: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5DBus.so.5: symbol dbus_message_set_allow_interactive_authorization, version LIBDBUS_1_3 not defined in file libdbus-1.so.3 with link time reference

Comment: @RamboPenguin the error is probably caused because Qt requires more modern libraries than ubuntu 14.04 provides, maybe if you install an older version of PyQt5 it works: `sudo python3.6 -m pip install pyqt5==5.9.2`, See https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5/#history, why is python 3.6 necessary?

Comment: Python 3.6 isn't needed necesarily - just python 3 in general. I was trying 3.6 because that is what I was using in Ubuntu 18.04 -- I will try your idea.

Comment: Thank you!! Got it fixed thanks to your suggestions. Much appreciated!! Installing an older version of pyqt worked! A note for anyone else that needs help in the future: I also did this - "sudo apt-get install -y libdbus-1-dev" before trying a different pyqt version. Not sure if it was necessary, but it was something I did before it worked.