# Python modules/packages can only be seen by a particular version of python 3 (Ubuntu 14.04.6)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pyqt5, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to install the following onto an Ubuntu 14.04.6 system:

- Qt5
- Python 3.6
- PyQt5
- Pyudev (version 0.20.0 or greater)

Currently, PyQt5 is the problem. When I run a python script as:

```
python3.6 myscript.py
```

Where myscript.py is:

```
import sys
import pyudev.pyqt5
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
```

I get an import error - "No module named QtCore".

So it is finding the PyQt5 package, but it cannot find QtCore or QtGui, etc.

The strange part is that when I run the below command, I do not get a QtCore import error, but instead I get a pyudev.pyqt5 import error.

```
python3 myscript.py
```

"python3" is referencing python3.4 when I do "python3 --version".

**Essentially, PyQt5 is only seen by python 3.4 and pyudev is only seen by python 3.6.**

This is how I installed everything based on a previous post: [Getting import error with sub modules of PyQt5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62745413/getting-import-error-with-sub-modules-of-pyqt5)
I changed the pyqt5 installation line from this other post because I got the error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyQt5 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found PyQt5
```

Installation process:

```
#install qt5
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential
sudo apt install qtcreator
sudo apt install qt5-default

#install pip
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.6
sudo apt-get install curl
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python3.6 -m pip install --upgrade pip

#install pyqt5
sudo apt install python3-pyqt5

sudo apt-get install '^libxcb.*-dev' libx11-xcb-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libxrender-dev libxi-dev libxkbcommon-dev libxkbcommon-x11-dev libfontconfig1

#install pyudev
pip install pyudev
```

My core question and issue:
**Why can pyudev and pyqt5 not both be imported into a python3.6 script?**

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If I am doing something totally wrong, please let me know. I am new to Ubuntu and trying to wrap my head around how everything works.

Comment: Hint: Python packages are never installed to just "Python". Every package is installed for exactly one Python version. If you gonna use 2 Pythons with the same or similar set of packages you have to install 2 set of packages, one for every Python.

Comment: Advice: Always use Python virtual environments. The only package to install outside of virtual environments is `virtualenv`. Also consider using `conda`.

Comment: @phd So how do I install a package for a particular python version? What is the method for doing that? I only need pyqt5 and pyudev to work on python3.6.

Comment: `pip3.6 install` or `python3.6 -m pip install`. Create and activate a virtual environment (with `virtualenv -p python3.6 venv; . venv/bin/activate`); then `pip install` or `python -m pip install` will also work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an unofficial repository so using apt-get python3-foopackage will not install foopackage in python3.6 but in system python3, so in [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62746343/6622587) I pointed out that you must install pip to install pyqt5 (an old version pyqt5), and you should do the same with pyudev:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.6
sudo apt-get install curl
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
sudo python3.6 get-pip.py
sudo python3.6 -m pip install --upgrade pip
sudo python3.6 -m pip install pyqt5==5.9.2
sudo apt-get install '^libxcb.*-dev' libx11-xcb-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libxrender-dev libxi-dev libxkbcommon-dev libxkbcommon-x11-dev libfontconfig1
sudo python3.6 -m pip install pyudev
```

and then you run your script using python3.6, not python3.

```
python3.6 myscript.py
```

Comment: Ok, I understand that pip should be used. The problem is, when I tried installing on a different computer (still Ubuntu 14.04.6), the "sudo python3.6 -m pip install pyqt5==5.9.2" gives me an error. (the one I described in the post). "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyQt5 (from versions: none)". Do you have any idea what would be the cause of this?

Comment: @RamboPenguin That had not already been solved in the previous post? Are you sure you have followed all the steps? Do both PCs have the same characteristics, for example both are 64-bit?

Comment: no, I guess I am not totally sure. I sent these exact steps to another person to install on their computer. To my knowledge this is what they typed in. I will verify.... @eyllanesc

Comment: @RamboPenguin Recommendation: If someone else is going to execute the commands it is recommended that 1) you create a script that executes all the steps, or 2) you take care of having all the evidence that each step was executed (for example images of what you get at execute each step). If the PC is 32 bits then you will have to compile pyqt5 since the company only provides binaries for 64 bits

Comment: It is 32 bit! My original system was 64 bit. What needs to change if it is 32 bit?

Comment: @RamboPenguin unfortunately you will have to compile pyqt5 for 32 bit, and that is annoying.

Comment: terrible..... Thank you for your help, once again. I will mark this as resolved for now then.